# How to fetch rows based on CRM modifiedon column

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I need to pull all rows from an entity which were modified recently. I am using the following statement which gives me an error

```
from e in myEntity
where e.ModifiedOn.HasValue
select e.cust_name
```

The error states

Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method. 
Message Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method.

Comment: modifiedon has always a value

Comment: Please define recently...modified in the last week? modified in the last month?

Comment: I need values modified in a particular date range. Thanks for the comments. The modified != null at least took care of the error I was receiving before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
from e in myEntity
where e.ModifiedOn != null
select e.cust_name
```

Comment: `ModifiedOn` is never null so this returns all records. How can this possibly be the correct answer?

Comment: Nicknow: Query in CRM is very restricted. Almost all the time you have to compare on the right, letting the left operator only for the attributes.

Comment: @Sxntk - I'm well aware of the Dynamics CRM LINQ provider requirements. That said, the comparison of not null (`!= null`) is __ALWAYS__ true because in Dynamics CRM `ModifiedOn` is never going to be `null`.

Comment: @Nicknow Sure, I'm not saying that's wrong, but the problem here was the query itself, not the condition. We can go far and ask the people why they are doing that but if is ok for them the answer, it's ok for us.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Lambda Expressions**:

```
var getModified = myEntity.where(w=>w.ModifiedOn!=null).select(s=>s.cust_name);
```